# Keep getting 'illegal tag "body"' on iFrame app

Tags: iframe, facebook-fbml

I've written tons of basic FB apps, all created as iFrame apps. I tried to install a new one today and all of a sudden, I'm getting this error:

App Temporarily Unavailable
Parse errors:
FBML Error (line 13): illegal tag "body" under "fb:tab-position"

I'm confused: this is an IFRAME app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like it's being parsed as FBML - are you sure it's actually an iframe app - for old apps there's a different setting for FBML and iframe modes, accessed via the app's advanced settings - [image: See here for an example of what the setting looks like]

Comment: Turns out it was an old app the the previous admin has set up as an fbml app, then changed to iframe. For some reason, FB didn't recognize the change. Deleting the app and creating it as a new one fixed the problem.